# Mysql : Failed to start the job error

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

When i am trying to install mysql server 5.5 on ubuntu 12.04,
I get this error while installing it.

Not able to figure out why

```
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: looks similar.. [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/384234/e-mysql-server-5-5-installation-error)

Comment: @codepiper I saw that post but the answers given on that question does not solves my problem.
Maybe in my case the solution is different